# Is this the most efficient way of doing this TSQL calculation of datediff

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, datetime

I have a table of data similar to below where I need to calculate the sum of all the paused time up until today. The columns can have any date in them, so PauseStart can be a future date , and PauseEnd can also be a future date. A Null date (20991231) is considered open ended, i.e. no end date to the pause was selected.

NB : Dates are UK date format

**The data**

```
PauseID RecID   PauseStart              PauseEnd
1022    10      2013-01-04 15:52:04.320 2013-01-21 00:00:00.000
1023    10      2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
1024    10      2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 2099-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

The data above shows that we had a pause between 1/1/2013 and 2/1/2013, a pause between 4/1/2013 and 21/1/2013 (which should register in the sum as 4/1/2013 to 7/1/2013 11:00:00) and 5/1/2013 -> open (which should register in the sum as 5/1/2013 to 7/1/2013 11:00:00)

The columns are not indexed.

**The TSQL** which I have come up with looks like this

```
SELECT 
    SUM (
    CASE 
    WHEN NULLIF(PauseEnd,'20991231') IS NULL THEN
        DATEDIFF(mi, PauseStart, ISNULL(NULLIF(PauseEnd,'20991231'), GetDate()))
    WHEN PauseEnd > GetDate() THEN
        DATEDIFF(mi, PauseStart, GetDate())
    ELSE
        DATEDIFF(mi, PauseStart, ISNULL(NULLIF(PauseEnd,'20991231'), GetDate()))
    END
        ) AS Datedifference
    FROM Pauses
WHERE Pauses.RecID = 10
AND PauseStart < GetDate()
```

This gives me the results

```
4021
1440
3533
```

which seem correct, however my question remains,

**Is this the most efficient way of achieving this result?**

addendum, this table could start holding millions of records, so I'd like to make the tsql that calculates the sum efficient in the first instance.

Comment: I don't think it makes any performance difference, but the first line in your case statement `WHEN NULLIF(PauseEnd,'20991231') IS NULL THEN` I think would be more readable as `WHEN PauseEnd = '20991231' THEN`. Minor thing, I know ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT 
PauseStart,
DATEDIFF(mi, PauseStart, CASE  WHEN PauseEnd > GetDate() THEN GetDate() ELSE PauseEnd END) as Datedifference
FROM Pauses
WHERE Pauses.RecID = 10 AND PauseStart < GetDate()
```

Comment: interesting, I have obviously missed out the fact that null (20991231) is always going to be greater then GetDate()

Comment: well for the next 86 years anyway, by which time I hope we've evolved beyond TSQL.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about it being nullable

Comment: The date is always stored as 31/12/2099 00:00:00 if it's openended. PauseEnd is a required field and isn't nullable

Comment: You do not need to do any null checks at all